# Django load model folder images

Tags: django

I have a user model similar to this:

```
def usr_img_path(instance, filename):
  return 'Usr/{}/{}'.format(instance.name, filename)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    images_folder = models.ImageField(upload_to=usr_img_path)
```

so this uploads an image to the user's name folder.
The problem is.. I'd like to have more than 1 image in that folder..
How do I fetch them?

I tried something like this in a template:

```
{% for user in users %}
  {% for image in user.images_folder %}
    <p>{{image.name}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but this didn't work. Should I make models for the Folder and the Images or is there a better way?

Comment: `ImageField` stores the path to a single image. You can see this in `user.image_folder.name`. You're going to want to ditch that `image_folder` field and instead set up a second `UserImage` model. That model would have a foreign key to a `User`, and an `ImageField`. You'd then access a users images with `user.userimage_set.all()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try making another model for the image and give that a foreign key to user. Like so:

```
def usr_img_path(instance, filename):
  return 'Usr/{}/{}'.format(instance.name, filename)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="images")
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=usr_img_path)
```

Then the template code would look like so:

```
{% for user in users %}
  {% for img in user.images.all %}
    <img src="{{img.url}}" />
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```